Bug that requires a lot of "Djongo migrate"
I'm using djongo.
I don't know what the cause is, but a message asking me to run python manage migrate appears from time to time.
Does anyone know the cause?
please.
this is my code
below code is app/models
model
from djongo import models

class RealTime(models.Model):
    _id = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    site = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url = models.URLField()
    create_time = models.DateTimeField()
    GPTAnswer = models.TextField()
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'realtimebest'

class Daily(models.Model):
    rank = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url = models.URLField()
    create_time = models.DateTimeField()

below code is Schema
schema
import graphene
from graphene_django.types import DjangoObjectType
from graphene import Mutation

from .views import board_summary
from .communityWebsite.models import RealTime, Daily

class RealTimeType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = RealTime

class DailyType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Daily

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    all_realtime = graphene.List(RealTimeType)
    all_daily = graphene.List(DailyType)

    def resolve_all_realtime(self, info, **kwargs):
        return RealTime.objects.all()

    def resolve_all_daily(self, info, **kwargs):
        return Daily.objects.all()

class SummaryBoardMutation(Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        board_id = graphene.String(required=True)

    response = graphene.String()

    def mutate(self, info, board_id):
        response = board_summary(board_id)
        return SummaryBoardMutation(response=response)

class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    summary_board = SummaryBoardMutation.Field()

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)

settings.py
# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     "corsheaders",

    # Graph QL
    'graphene_django',
    'graphene_mongo',
    
    'webCrwaling',
    'kingwangjjang',
    'chatGPT'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'kingwangjjang.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        # 'DIRS': [],
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'kingwangjjang.wsgi.application'

# Database
# MongoDB settings
DB_URI = 'mongodb://'+ DB_HOST + '/' + DB_USER + ':' + DB_PASSWORD
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': DB_NAME,
        'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': True,
        'CLIENT': {
            'host': DB_URI
        }  
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ko-kr'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Seoul'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# GRAPHENE = {
#     "SCHEMA": "webCrwaling.schema.schema"
# }

Insert Data
def get_real_time_best(self):
    req = requests.get('https://www.dcinside.com/', headers=self.g_headers[0])
    html_content = req.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
    li_elements = soup.select('#dcbest_list_date li')
    already_exists_post = []

    for li in li_elements:
        p_element = li.select_one('.box.besttxt p')
        a_element = li.select_one('.main_log')
        time_element = li.select_one('.box.best_info .time')

        if p_element and a_element and time_element:
            p_text = p_element.get_text(strip=True)
            a_href = a_element['href']
            no_value = a_href.split('no=')[-1]
            time_text = time_element.get_text(strip=True)

            if(time_text.find('-') > 0): 
                break  # 오늘 것만 추가 (이전 글은 제외 (DB에서 확인))

            # 시간 13:40 -> 2024.01.29 13:40 로 수정
            now = datetime.now()
            hour, minute = map(int, time_text.split(':'))
            # 시간 설정 및 datetime 객체 생성
            target_datetime = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, hour, minute)

            try:
                existing_instance = RealTime.objects.filter(_id=no_value).first()
                if existing_instance:
                    already_exists_post.append(no_value)
                    continue
                else:
                    RealTime.objects.get_or_create(
                        _id=no_value,
                        defaults={
                            'site' : 'dcinside',
                            'title': p_text,
                            'url': a_href,
                            'create_time': target_datetime,
                            'GPTAnswer': DEFAILT_GPT_ANSWER
                        }
                    )
            except IntegrityError:
                continue

    print("already exists post", already_exists_post)

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
Could this be a problem?
What part needs to be modified to solve the problem of data completely disappearing?
help me please.

It might help if you share the models that appear each time in the migration, since that is likely where the problem originates from.

check your models files you may be having problem like this one that was bugging me
class UserModel(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
   date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())

I was invoking the timezone.now like this (timezone.now()) when really what I should be doing is just --> (timezone.now)
class UserModel(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
   date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

to not invoke it, as every time I am doing any change to the db it was changing the field date_joined to the current date due to the fact I am invoking the function now so django thinks I want to update this field on all instances to the current date
so in a nut shell see if you are invoking any time function,
you maybe invoking any other type of function like for instance you are having you custom id and invoking the uuid like this
class UserModel(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
  id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4())

